# Python define parameter issues

Tags: python, random, dice, function

My program rolls *n* die depending on input however only ever does on at a time. tried making it go back to d20() with another one in the if but doesn't seem to do anything.

```
import random

min = 1;
print "1. d20 \n2. d12 \n3. d10 \n4. d8 \n5. d6 \n6. d \n7. d100"
command = raw_input("Function: ")


def d20(n):
    done = 0
    if n>done:
      print random.randint(min, 20)
      done = done + 1
    elif n==done :
     print 'finished'

if command == "d20" or command == "1":
    die = raw_input("How many die? ")
    int(die)
    d20(die)
else:
    print 'else'
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking...

Comment: What happens when you run your program and how is it different from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you're asking is how to re-run `d20` `n` times, where `n` is the number of dice you chose.

That is not the job for an `if` statement, but for a `for` loop.

```
import random
min_value = 1
print "1. d20 \n2. d12 \n3. d10 \n4. d8 \n5. d6 \n6. d \n7. d100"
command = raw_input("Function: ")

def d20(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print random.randint(min_value, 20)

if command == "d20" or command == "1":
    die = raw_input("How many dice? ")
    n = int(die)
    d20(n)
else:
    print 'else'
```

Output:

```
Function: 1
How many dice? 3
5
17
13
```

I have also changed the name from `min` to `min_value` because `min` is a python built-in function that returns a minimum of an iterable and you should not reassign it. Also you don't need `;` there.

Notice also that `n = int(die)` is **NOT** a safe command, there's nothing guaranteeing that you'll write an integer there. If you write a string that can't be converted to integer (i.e. "a"), python will raise an exception.

Happy dnd-ing.